# Select each value in turn in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sum, sql-server-2012

Using SQL Server 2012.

I have a `select` statement that selects a list of 24 values (floats) from a linked server.

How do I go about selecting each value applying a calculation to it (say * 100) and then summing the resulting values?

Just want a place to start as I am not getting anywhere.

**UPDATE**: the calculation will be the same for each value

Comment: Do you need the 24 values, or just the sum of the calculations?

Comment: no just the sum, I need to end on one figure

Comment: Are the 24 values in separate columns or on separate rows?

Comment: they are on separate rows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use your `SELECT` statement as a subquery:

```
SELECT SUM(YourValue *100)
FROM (Your SELECT statement
     ) as Sub
```

Or likely just add the aggregate to your `SELECT` without it being a subquery:

```
SELECT SUM(YourValue *100)
FROM YourTable
```

Update:  Simple example of above - [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/6838d/1/0)

Comment: If all he wants is the sum, the subquery is not required.

Comment: Based on the question, second option would work fine

Comment: I have 24 values how do I loop through each one, apply the calc then sum the 24 results

Comment: That's exactly what the above does.

Comment: @user2050577 In the above queries, the value is multiplied by 100 and aggregated, there's no looping necessary.

Comment: SUM(YourValue) * 100 is slightly faster than SUM(YourValue*100)

Comment: sorry I was very confused, I have used the second one and it works perfectly.  THanks